# Query created by ElasticSearchRepository returns data, but doesn't parse it into Java Object. Repo returns empty list when the query returns data

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am able to index documents successfully however when I try to query data using the repo, it returns an empty list. When I click the URL that spring data ES generates it appears to return data successfully but it doesn't parse them into a java object.  I am extending my document classes from a base class, so I tried removing that from the equation and it still returns an empty list.

I am using:
Spring Boot v2.5.6
Spring Data Elasticsearch v4.2.6
Elasticsearch v7.15.1

I am using the automatically generated query created by the Elasticsearch Repository:

```java
    public interface MaildatIMBRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<MaildatIMB, String> {
        List<MaildatIMB> findMaildatIMBByImb(String imb);
    }
```

In the service below you can see several attempts I have made. All of them are returning an empty list, yet the ES query seems to show *something* being returned

Service:

```java
@Service
public class MaildatIMBService {

    private final MaildatIMBRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public MaildatIMBService(MaildatIMBRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public List<MaildatIMB> hardMatchLookup(UspsErrorEvent uspsErrorEvent){
    // uspsErrorEvent.barcodeScanned is a String

//        return repository.findMaildatIMBSByImbEquals(uspsErrorEvent.barcodeScanned);
//        return repository.findMaildatIMBByImb(uspsErrorEvent.barcodeScanned);
//        List<MaildatIMB> results = repository.findByImb(uspsErrorEvent.barcodeScanned);
        List<MaildatIMB> results = repository.findMaildatIMBByImb(uspsErrorEvent.barcodeScanned);
//        return repository.findByImb(uspsErrorEvent.barcodeScanned);
        return results;

    }

}
```

ES Document Base Class:

```java
    @Setting(settingPath = "static/es-settings.json")
    public class IMBDocument {
    
        @Id
        @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
        private String id;
    
        @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
        private String sourceName;
    
        @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
        private String imb;
    
        @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
        private String sourceType;
    
        //Getter/Setter/constructors and additional fields left out
    
    }
```

ES Document Extended Class:

```java
    @Document(indexName = Indices.MAILDAT_IMB,shards = 2)
    public class MaildatIMB extends IMBDocument {
    
    
        public MaildatIMB() {
        }
    
        public MaildatIMB(String id, String sourceName, String imb, String sourceType, String crid, String stid, String mid, Integer serialNo, Integer docNo, Integer pieceNo, Integer trayNo, Integer packageNo, Integer palletNo, String pieceDesc1, String pieceDesc2, String pieceDesc3, String jobId1, String jobIdUSPS, Date importDate) {
            super(id, sourceName, imb, sourceType, crid, stid, mid, serialNo, docNo, pieceNo, trayNo, packageNo, palletNo, pieceDesc1, pieceDesc2, pieceDesc3, jobId1, jobIdUSPS, importDate);
        }
    }
```

ES Config Class:

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.asdf.asdf.elasticsearch")
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.asdf.asdf.elasticsearch"})
    public class ElasticConfig extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {
    
        @Value("${elasticsearch.url}")
        public String elasticsearchUrl;
    
        @Bean
        @Override
        public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
            final ClientConfiguration config = ClientConfiguration.builder()
                    .connectedTo(elasticsearchUrl)
                    .build();
            return RestClients.create(config).rest();
        }
    }
```

Results for Hibernate generated query:

```json
    // 20211122083947
    // http://localhost:9200/prod_imb/_search?typed_keys=true&max_concurrent_shard_requests=5&ignore_unavailable=false&expand_wildcards=open&allow_no_indices=true&ignore_throttled=true&search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch&batched_reduce_size=512&ccs_minimize_roundtrips=true
    
    {
      "took": 11,
      "timed_out": false,
      "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
      },
      "hits": {
        "total": {
          "value": 10000,
          "relation": "gte"
        },
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [
          {
            "_index": "prod_imb",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "QzKnRX0BSWKCjJABxMPJ",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
              "_class": "com.asdf.asdf.service.data.prodimb.ProdIMB",
              "imb": "0008112345678812979372204257347",
              "stid": "081",
              "mid": "123456789",
              "serialNo": 129793,
              "docNo": 1997,
              "pieceNo": 1655,
              "trayNo": 10,
              "packageNo": 1,
              "palletNo": 0,
              "pieceDesc1": "***AUTO**SCH 5-DIGIT 722",
              "pieceDesc2": "asdf",
              "pieceDesc3": "",
              "jobId1": "198923",
              "jobIdUSPS": "ABCDEFG ",
              "importDate": "20211122T031921.419Z"
            }
          },
            "_index": "prod_imb",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "TDKnRX0BSWKCjJABxMPJ",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
              "_class": "com.asdf.asdf.service.data.prodimb.ProdIMB",
              "imb": "0008112345678912980272113701005",
              "stid": "081",
              "mid": "123456789",
              "serialNo": 129802,
              "docNo": 2006,
              "pieceNo": 1370,
              "trayNo": 8,
              "packageNo": 1,
              "palletNo": 0,
              "pieceDesc1": "***AUTO**SCH 5-DIGIT 721",
              "pieceDesc2": "asdf",
              "pieceDesc3": "",
              "jobId1": "198923",
              "jobIdUSPS": "ABCDEF ",
              "importDate": "20211122T031921.419Z"
            }
          },
          //Removed extra for brevity
        ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: HOw do you create the query in your code? which versions of Spring Data Elasticsearch, Elasticsearch and Spring Boot do you use? And: Spring Data Elasticsearch has nothing to do with Hibernate or JPA.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my question with the requested info

Comment: Can you boil that down to a minimal sample repo with a compilable application so I can debug through that code to see what's happening?